# Логика в майнере nheqminer

Tags: c++, сервер, криптография, обработка, транзакции

Есть задание, написать свой майнер, за основу взял nheqminer(https://github.com/nicehash/nheqminer), пул выбрал Nanopool, всевозможной документации про криптовалюту и в частности zcash перечитал уйму. На данный момент программа подключается к пулу, получает от него задачу при запросе работы, вот такой пакет:

> {"id":null,"params":["1506538913","04000000","385f3c27b9269a700a9aa8bfa2b69433a7fddf7709635f9dafae430500000000","e3979e47d940ef232e1138059d2f 46b0b7406a914d5285a73d9f52ae26b3612c","0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","8db2cc59","995 5101c","true"],"method":"mining.notify"}

внутренности "params" раскидал по переменным, а вот что дальше делать не пойму, в исходнике исследуемого майнера довольно запутанно все. Т.е. какие конкретно вычисления надо сделать что бы потом результат отправить обратно на сервер и получить награду?

[image: получение транзакции]

Comment: Добавьте вывод с консоли текстом, а не скрином

Comment: .. и отформатируйте вопрос пожалуйста.